# How to create a method for an array of arrays in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am clearly missing something fundamental here. How can I change the second method of my function to accept `c`? Additionally, I would really prefer to use `AbstractArray` instead of `AbstractVector` as the type so as not to restrict the dimension either, but I wanted to cut down on potential sources of error.

```
function f(x::AbstractVector{Int})
    println(x)
end # f (generic function with 1 method)

function f(x::AbstractVector{AbstractVector{Int}})
    for i in x
        println(i)
    end
end # f (generic function with 2 methods)

a=[1,2,3] # 3-element Array{Int64,1}:
b=[4,5,6] # 3-element Array{Int64,1}:
c=[a,b] # 2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:

typeof(a) <: AbstractVector{Int} # true
typeof(c) <: AbstractVector{AbstractVector{Int}} # false

f(a) # [1, 2, 3]
f(c) # ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Array{Array{Int64,1},1})
```

Comment: Take a look at [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758161/methoderror-when-dispatching-on-a-parametric-vector-of-vectors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Composite-Types):

> Concrete Point types with different values of T are never subtypes of each other:
>
> ```
> julia> struct Point{T} end
>
> julia> Point{Float64} <: Point{Int64}
> false
>
> julia> Point{Float64} <: Point{Real}
> false
> ```
>
> This last point is very important: even though Float64 <: Real we DO NOT have Point{Float64} <: Point{Real}.

Translated to your example, as you noted,

```
julia> Vector{Int} <: AbstractVector{Int}
true

julia> Vector{Vector{Int}} <: AbstractVector{AbstractVector{Int}}
false
```

What you need here is

```
julia> Vector{Vector{Int}} <: AbstractVector{T} where T <: AbstractVector{Int}
true
```

or the convenient shorthand

```
julia> Vector{Vector{Int}} <: AbstractVector{<:AbstractVector{Int}}
true
```

Comment: 1. Why would `Float64` be a subtype of `Int64`? I don't follow that example or how it relates to my first type test.

2. `Int` is a supertype of `Int64` like `AbstractVector` is a supertype of `Vector`. I don't understand why the rules change arbitrarily at the third level i.e. why don't I need `<:AbstractVector{<:Int}}`?

3. Are there any additional code changes that I need to use `AbstractArray` in place of `AbstractVector`?

Comment: 1. The example is perhaps taken out of context a bit since I only quoted part of the section. I suggest you read the full section to get the context. 2. The rules don't change; `Int === Int64` (on a 64-bit system) so you can not compare the abstract type `AbstractVector` with the concrete type `Int`. You can, however, try with the abstract integer supertype `Integer` and see that the rules are consistent with what you see for `AbstractVector`. 3. I am not sure what you are asking; If you want to handle more than just vectors you can use `AbstractArray`.